# Handle negative time spans

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

In my output of a grid, I calculate a `TimeSpan` and take its `TotalHours`. e.g.

```
(Eval("WorkedHours") - Eval("BadgedHours")).TotalHours
```

The goal is to show the `TotalHours` as `39:44`, so I need to convert the value from `7.5` to `07:30`. This is no problem... unless it's negative!

I can create a `TimeSpan` object from `Hours` with

```
TimeSpan.FromHours( (Eval("WorkedHours") - Eval("BadgedHours")).TotalHours)
```

If it's negative, I can't convert it to a `DateTime` to use the `.ToString("HH:mm")` method, and the `TimeSpan` object does not support the format string.

Comment: Please consider reformatting the code snippets as inline code or code sections, and add the appropriate platform tag (I'd guess .NET from your snippets).

Comment: Note that a difference between 2 **TimeOnly** values is different -it is always positive and can be confusing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73039686/timespan-calculation-is-different-between-timeonly-and-datetime#comment129031324_73039686

Answer (score 107):

Isn't there a [`TimeSpan.Duration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.duration?view=net-6.0) method? I think this would handle what you are trying to do.

> Returns a new TimeSpan object whose value is the absolute value of the current TimeSpan object.

Comment: This is the easiest way, just subtract your two DateTimes, call Duration() on the result, and then do TotalHours.

Answer (score 12):

```
static string ToHMString(TimeSpan timespan) { 
    if (timespan.Ticks < 0) return "-" + ToHMString(timespan.Negate());

    return timespan.TotalHours.ToString("#0") + ":" + timespan.Minutes.ToString("00");
}

Console.WriteLine(ToHMString(TimeSpan.FromHours(3)));       //Prints "3:00"
Console.WriteLine(ToHMString(TimeSpan.FromHours(-27.75)));  //Prints "-28:45"
```

This will also work correctly if the timespan is longer than 24 hours.

Answer (score 10):

Just multiply it by -1 or use an absolute value function.

Comment: For anyone who googled it: use `TimeSpan.Duration` method. From MSDN: "Returns a new TimeSpan object whose value is the absolute value of the current TimeSpan object".

Answer (score 9):

There is a Negate method in the TimeSpan class.

Link to the MSDN documentation:
[TimeSpan.Negate Method()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.negate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution would be to do:

```
string format = "HH:mm";
if(hours < 0)
  format = "-" + format;

hours = Math.Abs(hours)
```

Answer (score 2):

its working .try this

mytimespam.Negate();

Comment: time *spam*, hehe ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi i worked this into a bit of code i have been writing, hope it helps

(results) is an int variable

`(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(result)) < TimeSpan.Zero ? "-" + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(result).ToString(@"hh\:mm") : "" + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(result).ToString(@"hh\:mm");`

Answer (score 1):

I checked to  every where.But i didnt get a correct answer that why i used this way to finish

```
TimeSpan diff = actualout.Subtract(actualin);
 string a =(diff.ToString()).ToString();
if(a.Contains("-"))
 {        
 diff = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Much more simple way is to just compare `if (diff < TimeSpan.Zero)`

Answer (score 1):

```java
TimeSpan Diff = Date1 - Date2;

if ((int)Diff.TotalDays < 0) { // your code }
```