# How to add two time span values having negative sign in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I have two columns in my table i-e Working Hours and Extra Hours for  employee attendance and total time that employee has to work is nine (9) hours if somebody check in at 9 o ' clock and check out at 11 o ' clock then system automatically calculate his/her working hours and extra hours now in this case working hours will be 2 hours and extra hours will be in negative form e.g -7:00:00 hours because employee leave 7 hours before actual time and i stored this negative value as "varchar" in database for user facilitation to understand either employee worked more from given time or less.Now i need to add these extra hours of employee for creating summary of month but i don't know how to add these negative time span and when i convert it to timeofday format then system cannot convert it due to negative sign.

I calculate sum of working hours after reading it from database as:

```
wrkhrs=wrkhrs.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["WorkHrs"].ToString()).TimeOfDay);
```

and i found some code for subtraction as:

```
TimeSpan exthrs = org_work.Subtract(tot_work);
```

but if timespan have negative sign then it don't work.
if any body have any idea then kindly share it . thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
public Tuple<string,string>  Calculate_Hours(int id,DateTime strt, DateTime end)
        {
            TimeSpan wrkhrs = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan exthrs=new TimeSpan(0,0,0);
            //select * from vw_Rept_Attend where UserID ='" + id + "' and convert(date,AtnDate) between '" + strt.Date + "' and '" + end.Date + "'
            cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Calculate_Hours_For_Report", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", strt.Date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end.Date);
            conn.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (dr["WorkHrs"].ToString().Length>0)
                   wrkhrs=wrkhrs.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["WorkHrs"].ToString()).TimeOfDay);
               if (!dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().Contains("-") && dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().Length > 0)
                {
                    exthrs = exthrs.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString()).TimeOfDay);
                }
                else if (dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().Contains("-") && dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().Length > 0)
                {
                    string ext = dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().Substring(dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().LastIndexOf("-") +1);
                    exthrs = exthrs.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(ext).TimeOfDay);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            dr.Close();
           return new Tuple<string, string>(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (int)TimeSpan.Parse(wrkhrs.ToString()).TotalHours, Math.Abs((int)TimeSpan.Parse(wrkhrs.ToString()).Minutes), Math.Abs((int)TimeSpan.Parse(wrkhrs.ToString()).Seconds)), string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (int)TimeSpan.Parse(exthrs.ToString()).TotalHours, Math.Abs((int)TimeSpan.Parse(exthrs.ToString()).Minutes), Math.Abs((int)TimeSpan.Parse(exthrs.ToString()).Seconds)));

        }
```

and called out put of above function as:

```
var mytuple = Calculate_Hours(id,Convert.ToDateTime(dtStart.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(dtEnd.Text));
string tot_workHrs= mytuple.Item1;
string tot_ExtHrs=  mytuple.Item2;
```

above is my logic that i retrieve my correct output, if someone has any question then please feel free to ask me by creating new comment on this post.

hope now this will be helpful for all....

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: i have only code for adding time span

Comment: Pleas add in question.

Comment: it's really hard to understand what you are asking from the way your question is formatted.  Breaking this up into sentences would help, and providing some code would be preferred.

Comment: Can you show the input and desired output?

Comment: i updated my question and add some code line. now it might be helpful to understand

Comment: Please check my answer. Why `TimeStamp.Duration` is not good enough for you? Also check this link, it can handle it: http://www.dotnetperls.com/timespan. Also what do you mean by "if timespan have negative sign then it don't work". How is that? Error? In which particular point of you code it fails?

Comment: it gives an error that this is not a valid datetime object

Comment: thanks for your time i created a logic just now and now it works perfectly. i build myself function.

Comment: At least please share it with us in your Q so that we might understand your question properly at the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.
Use `TimeSpan.Duration()`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration(v=vs.110).aspx

> "Returns a new TimeSpan object whose value is the absolute value of
>   the current TimeSpan object"

2.
Or some code from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1018814/1806838):

```
static string ToHMString(TimeSpan timespan) { 
    if (timespan.Ticks < 0) return "-" + ToHMString(timespan.Negate());

    return timespan.TotalHours.ToString("#0") + ":" + timespan.Minutes.ToString("00");
}

Console.WriteLine(ToHMString(TimeSpan.FromHours(3)));       //Prints "3:00"
Console.WriteLine(ToHMString(TimeSpan.FromHours(-27.75)));  //Prints "-28:45"
```

Comment: i don't need absolute value some of the value may be negative then how to handle negative calculation?

Comment: @Waqas Updated answer, please check.

Comment: Also if you store it as string (which is not recommended at all) just use the absolute value and put a negative sign before it.

Comment: if i store it as time span in database then database cannot accept negative time span at all i tried it earlier so then i saved it as string

Comment: So your issue is how to store negative time in the db? Now you store it as string, that should still work. If not, then simply store all as positive and have a bool attribute in your datatabe which tells you if that is +/-.

Comment: thanks for your time i created a logic just now and now it works perfectly. i build myself function.

Answer (score 3):

First of all it is a bad idea to store a time/duration value as `string` in the database.

Second the `.Net` `TimeSpan` structure is perfectly able to represent negative durations and calculate with these correctly.

Suggestions:

1. Store your negative duration as a time/duration value in the databese. If your database has no duration type which supports negative values add a boolean "This value is negative"
2. In your C# code use `TimeSpan` and the usual operators: `+`and `-`

Comment: +1, though duration values are usually best stored as integers for some predefined precision, such as minutes, seconds, or milliseconds.  For employee's work time, I suggest duration in minutes as an integer.   Note `time` in many databases (such as SQL Server) is time-of-day, not elapsed-time.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need?

```
string[] sample = new string[] { "2.1", "-7.0", "1.0" };

TimeSpan total =
    sample
        .Select(s => TimeSpan.FromHours(double.Parse(s)))
        .Aggregate((ts0, ts1) => ts0.Add(ts1));
```

The `total` I get is `-03:54:00` as a `TimeSpan`.